# SharePoint 2013 "Did you mean?"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

SharePoint 2013 "Did you mean?"

Hello,

The "Did you mean?" feature in SharePoint 2013 search is not working how I expect it to. Either this is a misunderstanding by me or an error so if someone could advise I would be grateful.

I have switched to a static spelling dictionary and I have added some exclusions:

Image

I have run the "Search Custom Dictionary Update" timer job (and also waited 48hrs)

When I search I would expect that SharePoint would not suggest any of the terms I have excluded, this however is not the case as you can see from the below screen shot.

[image]

[image]

If I search for renew blue badge I get "Did you mean" and it suggests two of the terms I have added to my exclusions.

I am a bit confused and assume I am doing this wrong.

Comment: make sure Search Custom Dictionaries Update timer jobs completed sucessfully?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I have checked the timer jobs and they are running successfully. I have also posed this question on the Microsoft Partner site and I got this reply:


I had tried this on my side, and  had the same results, please see the screenshot below. And from the below first link we can see it in the Important note “You can only include or exclude single words.” In my personal opinion, it means that when we only enter “renee“ or “madge” in the search box, the misspelling correction can be excluded.